# Deploying Rails 4 with Capistrano foreman environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I found some issues with a worker running in the development environment and need to customize the foreman export task to set the ENV to production somehow:

```
  task :export_worker, roles: :worker do
    foreman_export = "foreman export --app #{application} --user #{user} --concurrency worker=3,worker_slow=2,clock=1 --log #{shared_path}/log upstart /etc/init"
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{sudo} #{bundle_cmd} exec #{foreman_export}"
  end
```

Anyone know how I can set it to production when it runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreman has [an environment option](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#GLOBAL-OPTIONS) that can be used to load custom `.env` files. You could try using that to set the environment to production.

For example, if you had a `development.env` file containing the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=development
```

You could get Foreman to load it like this:

```
foreman export -e development.env -c worker=3,worker_slow=2,clock=1 upstart /etc/init
```

Then if you need to reference the environment in your `Procfile` (example assumes sidekiq worker):

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq --environment $RAILS_ENV
```

Heroku has [a nice article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) on setting up a `.env` file for use with Foreman.